# Trying to run an xslt for xml with eclipse but it does not work

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, xslt

I am trying to run a .xslt to show some info from a .xml to an html page in eclipse. I run it, and eclipse produces a .out.xml file which when I try to run with chrome I get the message :

> This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated
>   with it.

I am completely new in this so I cannot figure out what is going on...

XML FILE :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="html_xml.xslt"?>
<CarModel>
<Audi model = "TT" year = "2006" starting_price = "33.000$">
    <type>sport</type>
    <horse_power>222hp</horse_power>
    <drivetrain>quattro</drivetrain>
    <transmission>6_Manual</transmission>
</Audi>
<Mercedes model = "W222_S400" year = "2013" starting_price = "63.000$">
    <type>luxury</type>
    <horse_power>302hp</horse_power>
    <drivetrain>front_wheel_drive</drivetrain>
    <transmission>7_Automatic</transmission>
</Mercedes>
<BMW model = "X3_xDrive35i" year = "2010" staring_price = "40.000$">
    <type>crossover_SUV</type>
    <horse_power>302hp</horse_power>
    <drivetrain>quattro</drivetrain>
    <transmission>6_Manual</transmission>
</BMW>
</CarModel>
```

XSLT FILE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html><body><h2> Car Model Info </h2>
  <table border="1">
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="elem" select="/*"/>
  </table></body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template mode="elem" match="/*">
  <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
    <td><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></td>
    <td><xsl:apply-templates mode="child" select="/*/*"/> (c) </td>
    <td><xsl:apply-templates mode="attr" select="/*/@*"/> (a) </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template mode="child" match="/*/*">
  <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template mode="attr" match="/*/@*">
  <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XSLT OUTPUT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html><body><h2> Car Model Info </h2>
  <table border="1">
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="elem" select="/*"/>
  </table></body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template mode="elem" match="a:*">
  <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
    <td><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></td>
    <td><xsl:apply-templates mode="child" select="/*/*"/> (c) </td>
    <td><xsl:apply-templates mode="attr" select="/*/@*"/> (a) </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template mode="child" match="/*/*">
  <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template mode="child" match="/*/@*">
  <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Show us the XSLT output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eclipse seems to like its style sheets named with `.xsl` instead of `.xslt`.  At least, when I tried your style sheet and input XML in my environment, I renamed it as such and changing the second line of your XML to

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="html_xml.xsl"?>
```

and changing the second line of your XSL to

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
```

as suggested in another comment. After that, the following worked for me:

1. File named `input.xml` and `html_xml.xsl` in the same directory in an Eclipse project
2. Right-click on `input.xml` and select `Run As` -> `XSL Transformation`
3. Look for file named `input.out.html` generated

Answer (score 0):

Please save as **Out.html** file your output in eclipse. 
If you open html file with xml extension , we will get error as

```
 This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

<html>
  <body>
    <h2>Car Model Info</h2>
      <table border="1">
       <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
         <td>CarModel</td>
         <td>AudiMercedesBMW (c)</td>
         <td>(a)</td>
       </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi I have observered one more, might be typo error XSLFile is having wrong XSL namespace . Correct one is xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The code that you wrote is it a result from the one I submitted or you made it because my Out.xml does not have values but it is exactly the same as the .xslt ...

Comment: I have ran the same code in my local and saved to XML and opened in chrome. But we have to save the response in html file. If you are seeing same XSLT in Out.xml. There might be an error in XSLT or looking wrong output file.

Comment: One more possible of the same error. You are not giving proper input file to XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select XSLT file Run As -- Runconfiguration
2. Create New configuration under XSL
3. Select input file(test.xml) and transformation file (test.xslt)
4. Select classpath tab and under user entries  add external jar (Saxon-HE-9.5.0.1.jar)
5. Select Output file from ouput tab

Answer (score 0):

Select xml file and click on run as xsl transformation. 
     then
select file with .xsl and click ok. 
After that one file generated
    something.out.xml then 
change the extension of 
    something.out.xml to
    something.out.html
and run tht html file